# New domain keep pointing back to old server

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, migration

I am migrating my domain to a new host, 000webhost.com. but it keeps pointing back to my old hosting, biz.nf every time I tried to access it. I know there is a DNS propagate of 24-48 hours, but my website is showing fine under the proxy http://anonymouse.org/cgi-bin/anon-www.cgi/http://www.maryshao.com/ but not when I just type in maryshao.com

Why is my website only showing under the proxy website? Is it really just DNS propagate time?

Comment: I'd recommend running DNS health checks. Testing your domain indicates name server issues, and your SOA Expire time is set much too high for changes (3600000). You should work with your DNS provider's support to correct these issues.

Comment: There are some dns flush tools available as plugins, handy if you have this type of situation.

Comment: To clear the browsers caache easily, open history, rightclick the domainname and press 'forget website'. All DNS and cache will be removed

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it really does mean just a matter of time. It depends how long until a DNS server your going through has been updated on the new name-servers. For me right now that domain works fine with the new design as shown on the proxy, but my neighbour may be seeing something else being on a different ISP and therefore using different servers around the net etc.

You can refresh the client side of things your end by opening Command Prompt (Start - Run - cmd.exe), type in: **ipconfig /flushdns**. Then try the site again.

Also try clear your browsers cache.

Ultimately just give it time.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to DNS propagation only. During this time what is happening is that the DNS servers which your computer is configured to use (possibly set by your broadband router using DHCP, and likely pre-configured or assigned into your router by your Internet Service Provider), are not yet reflecting the changes you have made -- but the DNS servers that the Anonymouse service uses are using the updated records.

While you are waiting for your site to be accessible from everywhere with the right IP addresses you can check using this free propagation check website I use my self regularly for the same purpose (don't worry if not all return a result since some apply rate limits to the number of requests from this service per day, but it does often help reveal when some are not resolving to the correct IP addresses:

- https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/www.maryshao.com (to check your `www.maryshao.com` A record)
- https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/maryshao.com (to check your `@maryshao.com` A record)

This service checks a variety of DNS servers from around the world but obviously does not check all DNS servers - it can only give an indication of when it is likely that propogation may be mostly complete.

It is always worth checking both A records since they are independent and may take different lengths of time each to propogate.

According to [IntoDNS](http://www.intodns.com/maryshao.com) (which I would recommend from experience) your DNS server setup and configuation *is* healthy.

The *TTL* (Time-to-Live) for your A records: 86400 seconds = 1440 minutes = 24 hours.
Therefore the maximum time you should have to wait for propogation to complete for changing your A records is 24 hours (can't always be guaranteed).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is likely propagation if you can see the 'proper' site through an anonymizer.

Try clearing your browser cache and check again.  Other than that, patience.