# DNS resolves my hostname to 2 different IP's back and forth within minutes

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, nameserver, migration

We recently switched webhosts from Databse Mart to Liquid Web. This weekend we updated the name servers with our registrar and about 48 hours later, we saw our new site on `insidestl.com`. Now, a day later our old site starts showing up again! Every couple of minutes the site switches. When I used `http://whatsmydns.net/` it seems to have propagated to our new site.

Running ping on windows, about once a minute you can see it switches from our old ip, to our new back and forth.

```
Pinging insidestl.com [198.64.251.50] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 198.64.251.50: bytes=32 time=68ms TTL=108
Reply from 198.64.251.50: bytes=32 time=73ms TTL=108
Reply from 198.64.251.50: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=108
Reply from 198.64.251.50: bytes=32 time=69ms TTL=108

Ping statistics for 198.64.251.50:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 68ms, Maximum = 73ms, Average = 69ms

C:\Windows\system32>ping insidestl.com

Pinging insidestl.com [198.64.251.50] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 198.64.251.50: bytes=32 time=68ms TTL=108
Reply from 198.64.251.50: bytes=32 time=80ms TTL=108
Reply from 198.64.251.50: bytes=32 time=81ms TTL=108
Reply from 198.64.251.50: bytes=32 time=67ms TTL=108

Ping statistics for 198.64.251.50:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 67ms, Maximum = 81ms, Average = 74ms

C:\Windows\system32>ping insidestl.com

Pinging insidestl.com [67.227.192.78] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 67.227.192.78: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=50
Reply from 67.227.192.78: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=50
Reply from 67.227.192.78: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=50
Reply from 67.227.192.78: bytes=32 time=24ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 67.227.192.78:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 24ms, Maximum = 25ms, Average = 24ms

C:\Windows\system32>ping insidestl.com

Pinging insidestl.com [67.227.192.78] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 67.227.192.78: bytes=32 time=36ms TTL=50
Reply from 67.227.192.78: bytes=32 time=23ms TTL=50
Reply from 67.227.192.78: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=50
Reply from 67.227.192.78: bytes=32 time=25ms TTL=50

Ping statistics for 67.227.192.78:
Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
Minimum = 23ms, Maximum = 36ms, Average = 27ms
```

As you can see it switches back and forth between `67.227.192.78` which is the new IP and `198.64.251.50` which is our old one.

Comment: No problem found my end and tried using 3 different connections via my VPN. My guess is that your problem is local, not external. Possibly could be the DNS at your ISP playing up. You need to test it using a different ISP or a VPN.

Comment: I've done that several times. It seems to be a problem in St. Louis only.... happens on my phone's AT&T 4G, and my home's Charter internet.

Comment: I'm in West County on Charter. I'll try myself.

Comment: Well its not a server issue. Its your area.

Comment: I don't see the problem either. Do you have DNS settings in your router? Charter's DNS sucks.

Comment: First round of tests I did `.ro` `.nl` and `.uk` locations. All locations return correct IP address over several tests. I've just now tested from `Los Angeles`, `Chicago`, `Kansas City` and `Manassas`, all which returned the correct IP address again.

Comment: When testing on your mobile you need to disable WIFI otherwise testing your mobile from home will use the same connection. You most likely done this already but worth mentioning just in case.

Comment: It shows me the IP of the DNS server, but no options on DNS caching. I wrote a quick thing in Java to check the IP every 45 seconds. It was stable for about 3 minutes, then after 5 minutes went back to correct and has been stable for 20 minutes now. Maybe it resolved itself.

Comment: Routers using stock firmware generally don;'t have a 'CLEAR DNS' option, most use DNSMasq which will clear when you reboot the router. But if your going to clear the cache on the router ensure you do it in Windows too. Disable the network connection, then do a `ipconfig /flushdns` then clear the cache in your browser (these all cache too sadly), then once you done that, reboot your router :)

Comment: Then enable the network connection... then if it still does it! you know its not you :)

Comment: I just tried connecting to the site through my browser, and right after I did my Java program notified me that the resolving IP changed. I then repeatedly tried to connect through the browser and it kept switching...

Comment: These issues are off topic here and you need to ask them on serverfault.stackexchange.com I think I agree with Simon that this seems to be a Windows or local issue. (I'm betting Windows. It's always Windows.)

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/59518/new-domain-keep-pointing-back-to-old-server?rq=1

The SOA expire is 3600000 and that may have to do with the issue. This thread should probably be closed because I did ask the question on the wrong stackexcahnge site, as @Rob said.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that the ping time for the different IP addresses indicates you are being routed to different DNS servers for whatever reason. Some DNS servers take time to update though you waited 48 hours and it should have been completed by now.

I would suggest asking this question on serverfault if it doesn't resolve itself by the end of the day.